# Let $trcA=0$.why $A=M+N$ where $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ and $trcA=0$.why $A=M+N$  where $M$ and $N$  are nilpotent matrices?

Comment: are you claiming that if the trace of a matrix is zero, then it can be written as the sum of two nilpotent matrices?  what about $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}?$

Comment: @abel $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}=\pmatrix{\frac12&\frac14\\ -1&-\frac12}+\pmatrix{\frac12&-\frac14\\ 1&-\frac12}$.

Answer (score 4):

This is true if the underlying field is of characteristic zero. Over such a field, every traceless matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix $B$ with a zero diagonal (see [Kahan's proof](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf), for instance). Now, let $A=PBP^{-1}$. Split $B$ into the sum of its strictly upper triangular part $U$ and its strictly lower triangular part $L$. Then $A=PUP^{-1}+PLP^{-1}$ is a desired split.

The statement is not necessarily true over a finite field. For a counterexample, consider $I_2$ over $F=GF(2)$. The set of all nilpotent matrices in $M_2(F)$ is
$$
S=\left\{0,\,\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\,\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0},\,\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}\right\}.
$$
No two matrices in $S$ add up to $I_2$.